# Segue is not being transferred in (swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, overriding, segue

I am making a game that when a button is pressed twice, it will transfer to another view controller. Right now the users reaction time is timed in view controller a. I would like the time to be segued to view controller b and when in view controller b the time be subtracted by 1. Right now the time is not being segued. When the button is pressed twice the view controller changes but the text is not being transferred.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var labelx: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var startx: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var pressSoccerBall: UIButton!
    var level = 0
    var timer: Timer?
    var isRunning: Bool {
        get {
            return timer != nil
        }
    }
    var counter = 0.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        labelx.text = String(format: "%.1f", counter)
        startx.isEnabled = true
    }

    @IBAction func startTimer(_ sender: Any) {
        if isRunning {
            return
        }
        refreshTimer()
    }

    @IBAction func PressSoccerBall(_ sender: Any) {
        level += 1
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let DestViewController : winViewController = segue.destination as!      winViewController
        DestViewController.LebelText = labelx.text!
    }

    func refreshTimer() {

        if let timer: Timer = timer {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1,target: self,selector: #selector(updateTimer),userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        startx.isEnabled = false
    }

    func updateTimer() {
        counter += 0.1
        labelx.text = String(format: "%.1f", counter)
        if counter < 9.9 && level == 2 {
            let nextc =   self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "winViewController") as? winViewController
            self.present(nextc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: pic of vc a]

VIEW CONTROLLER B

```
import UIKit

class winViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var winningLabel: UILabel!
    public var LebelText: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        steve()
    }

    func steve(){

        guard let unwrapedText = self.LebelText else {
            return
        }
        if let myInt = Double(unwrapedText){
            let  myInt = myInt - 1
            self.winningLabel.text = String(myInt)

        } else {
            return
        }
    }

}
```

[image: PIC OF VIEW CONTROLLER B]

Comment: You should use delegates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using segues.  You are creating the `winViewController` and then calling present to show it.  So, `prepareForSegue` will never be called.

Simply set the `LebelText` property on `nextc` before presenting it:

```
func updateTimer() {
    counter += 0.1
    labelx.text = String(format: "%.1f", counter)
    if counter < 9.9 && level == 2 {
        if let nextc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "winViewController") as? winViewController {
            nextc.LebelText = labelx.text
            self.present(nextc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```